Configuring Micrometer to Automatically Create New Span on Async
I am trying to get Spring Boot 3.2 to work with trace/span ids in a similar fashion to the way Spring Cloud Sleuth works in Spring Boot 2.
I have come up with the following configuration class:
@Configuration
class MicrometerConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

     public static Executor executor() {
         return ContextExecutorService.wrap(ForkJoinPool.commonPool(), contextSnapshotFactory::captureAll);
     }

     private static final ContextSnapshotFactory contextSnapshotFactory = ContextSnapshotFactory.builder()
        .build();

     @Override
     public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
         return ContextExecutorService.wrap(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), contextSnapshotFactory::captureAll);
     }
 }

This is working for @Async methods, but does not create new spans for new threads. I tried putting a @NewSpan annotation on my @Async method, but this causes my method to not run asynchronously anymore.
I also tried putting a manual new span in form my async executor
@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    Span span = tracer.nextSpan();
    span.start();
    try (Tracer.SpanInScope ignored = tracer.withSpan(span)) {
        log.info("NEWSPAN");
        return ContextExecutorService.wrap(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), contextSnapshotFactory::captureAll);
    }
}

While the log.info("NEWSPAN"); does produce a new span in the log, the actual method is still producing the outside span id. What am I missing?

Set management.observations.annotations.enabled to true, and NewSpan annotation will be processed.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/actuator/observability.html#actuator.observability.annotations
